# Cue point event fires even if the flv is paused

Tags: actionscript-3, flash-cs5, flv

I have created a player that loads video FLV files and plays them in a sequence. On loading the videos I retrieve the total video time by stream.client.onMetaData = ns_onMetaData;” and in an EnterFrame event I check whether the video playtime is equal the totaltime. If the video playtime is equal to the totaltime then the player loads the next video. Sometime, even if the video ends, the playtime and total time doesn’t match. So to fix the issue, I decided to put an event cue point (END) at end of each video FLV. So whenever the FLV fires the END event, the player removes the current video and loads the next one.

Suppose the video total time is 44:00. The cue point is also at 44:00 in the FLV. So whenever the player gets the END event from the FLV then it loads the next one. Now the issue is, if I pause the video at 42:00 and wait for 2 sec, the player gets the END cue point and jumps to the next video. When I paused the video the timer says “42:00 of 44:00”. The timer doesn’t increase, that means the video has actually paused. But I still don’t understand that why I’m getting the END cue point where the video has not reached the time. Any suggestion??

Comment: I suspect two instances of the same video. Does you video have some sound so you can check if it is running in the background?

Comment: Thanks Kodiak. Below solution worked :) Yes, it has and I checked its not running in the background.

Comment: I thought of that one, if ever you get an answer for your weird cue point firing issue, tell me :)

Answer (score 0, accepted):

if you need to know when your video ends, add a listener for [`NetStatusEvent.NET_STATUS`](http://help.adobe.com/en_US/FlashPlatform/reference/actionscript/3/flash/events/NetStatusEvent.html#info) and check the `event.info.code` there, it's `"NetStream.Play.Stop"` when the video stops

Comment: Accepted the answer. Sorry didn't know the thing... I'm very new to this forum :)